# can _open() return valid negative fd ?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Is it possible that win32's `_open()` return valid FD that is negative ?

In other words, is comparison

```
 if( (fd=_open(...)) < 0) error...;
```

as safe as form

```
 if( (fd=_open(...)) == -1) error...;
```

?

I am asking because all msdn examples
are in form `if(fd == -1 )`, and never form `if( fd < 0)`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, for Windows code I would recommend using CreateFile() instead of _open(), which mainly exists for compatibility with other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Windows file descriptors are borrowed from MS-DOS 2.0 file handles, which were loosely based on Unix file descriptors, all of which are indices into the process's table of file control blocks. So a valid file handle must be non-negative.

Comment: The HANDLE returned by CreateFile is an index into the process's table of kernel objects. The FDs returned by the VCs _open are indexes into a table maintained by the msv c-runtime.

Comment: True, in MSC there is an extra level of indirection, i.e., a file descriptor is an index into a (process-specific) library table containing system file handles.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Negative values are all errors.  In fact, if you look at read(), it asserts the fd is between 0 and 31.

Comment: Woah.  This is a very interesting answer.  Real question: ` In fact, if you look at read(), it asserts the fd is between 0 and 31.`  Where did you find this information?

Comment: This would mean that there could only be up to 32 open files, which I doubt.